# Minimizing the error function

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification, numerical-methods, matrix-calculus

I need to recheck a proof for minimizing the error by finding optimum step-size. I re-checked the proof many times but still can't find a mistake although the number I am getting in Matlab is not expected, so please if any one is good with linear algebra can tell me If I have an obvious mistake.

here is my notation:

- $\hat{X}_t$ is function of $\mu$ and matrices of size $M \times N$
- $\mathbf{X_t}$, $\mathbf{Y_t}$, $\boldsymbol{\Omega_t}$ are constant matrices of size $M \times N$
- $\mathbf{A}$ is constant matrix $M \times R$, $\mathbf{B}$ is constant matrix of size $N \times R$ and $\mathbf{D}$ is constant matrix $R \times R$
- $\mu$, $\lambda$, $t$ are constant scalar values
- $\|\cdot\|_F$ denotes the Frobenius norm

[**My current proof:**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpKXi.png)

Comment: Please consider changing the title to something that describes the statement you're proving

Comment: done thank you for the edits